# How to export hazard ratio tables made with coxph and knitr::kable

Tags: r, markdown, survival-analysis, kable, cox-regression

It is rather challenging to produce a simplified code, so I added the export file from R markdown
I'm producing hazard ratio tables from survival data and I'm looping through multiple columns with the following code

````
   [```{r}
# take the variable names in df2
varnames <- colnames(df2clean)\[c(29:35)\]

lapply(varnames, function(i) {
  # STRING INTERPOLATION WITH sprintf, THEN CONVERTED TO FORMULA OBJECT
  iformula <- as.formula(sprintf("Surv(time = df2clean$TimeTo.Event, event = df2clean$event) ~ %s + Age + MI + Gender", i))  
  
  # RUN MODEL REFERENCING DYNAMIC FORMULA
 coxph(iformula, data=df2clean, na.action=na.omit) %>%
 
   # coxph to dataframe and table
   finalfit::fit2df(condense = FALSE) %>%
   knitr::kable(digits = c(0, 2, 3, 4, 5))
  

})
```][1]
````

In R studio the tables become visible without error messages. However when I export the table to HTML I dont get the tables produced by knitr::kable that I get with the code below (without the loop)

```
coxph(Surv(time= df2clean$TimeTo.Event, event = df2$event) ~ Dkk1 + Age + MI + Gender,
      data = df2clean) %>% 
     finalfit::fit2df(condense = FALSE) %>% 
     knitr::kable(digits = c(0, 2, 3, 4, 5))
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you show should work and it is tricky to advise without a reproducible example. As you say, this can be difficult.

Have you looked at `finalfit_permute()`. This does exactly what you want but gives each model as a column in a table.

Reference: https://finalfit.org/reference/ff_permute.html
Examples of final table: https://finalfit.org/articles/all_tables_examples.html#base-model-individual-explanatory-variables

```
# Specify base model variables
explanatory_base = c("Age", "MI", "Gender")

# Specify variables to permute through
explanatory_permute = c("FIXaAT", "FXa_AT", "FXIa_A1AT", "Dkk1")

# Produce final table
df2clean %>%
  finalfit_permute("Surv(TimeTo.Event, event", explanatory_base, explanatory_permute)
```

Exporting options are here: https://finalfit.org/articles/export.html